# How to setup a login with google in rails applicaiton?

Tags: authentication, oauth, omniauth

I use omniauth for login to socialnetworks. I am able to create an app in facebook and 
I can put my id and secret in the configuration file. But I am not able to do the same thing in google because I am not able to register the  url http://localhost:3000. I came to knew that google has some way to avoid the registration process using some certificate but I can't figure out how to do that. If anyone done that then please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There's a newer [omniauth plugin](https://rubygems.org/gems/google-api-omniauth) that uses [OAuth 2.0 for login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) that you might want to try.

Documentation is light, but there is a sample app in there and it's pretty easy to configure. Registering the client is also pretty easy through the [APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and is localhost friendly :)